# Upload Progress in Wicket for MultiFileUploadField

Tags: file-upload, upload, wicket, progress

Wickets UploadProgressBar does only work for 'FileUploadField'. This is insufficient for my needs as I need to transfer multiple files which will be added by the User (Just like it can be done with 'MultipleUploadField').
So I'd like to implement an UploadProgressBar which also works for the MultipleUploadField but don't know what would be the best approach to do this. I recognized the classes UploadInfo and UploadStatusResource which might be useful here.

Does anyone have a suggestion what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: `MultipleFileUploadField` is hacked together from some third party Javascript.  It might be helpful to look at the underlying JS to see exactly how each item is handled.  Specifically, the way it is currently implemented uploads the files in one submit (not several).  So, that may not be the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **Uploadify** at [www.uploadify.com](http://www.uploadify.com/), which uses Flash to upload multiple files. You can integrate its Javascript callbacks nicely into Wicket, using Wicket's JS features.

It brings a nice progress bar for each single file upload.

Or you can wait for **HTML 5**.

Meanwhile you can also check for a better Javscript library for multiple file uploads and again integrate it in Wicket.